# Solution for Generate next sequence number in race condition

Tags: c#, database, algorithm, architecture

I am facing the issue of generating a next sequence number (kind of invoice number). The Requirement are

1. There is no duplicate number.
2. There is no gap between those numbers.

The normal approach is

```
 1. Find the last number 
 2. Increase value 
 3. Insert new number
```

When we have multiple request at the same time, the 3rd step of First Request could be not yet complete and the First step of Second Request has been started. and it lead to duplicate numbers.
There are some solutions for it 
 **1. Using transaction and lock**. 
Bad thing about it is there is a waiting there and it slow the app. Moreover, we have more than 1 databases involve, that make us have to enable DTC in all DB servers and app server. 
**2. Using Pre-Generate number and Azure Queue Storage** 
 1. PreCreated a queue that contain a list of number that you gonna
    use 
 2. Pop out a last number. Return the number back to the queue incase there is an exception in using it. Do nothing if nothing happen 
 3. Auto push in number every mid night (or every hour) 
 4. Manual function trigger inserting number if it's run out of value

**My Question is: Which way is better and is there any other solutions for this kind of problem.**

**UPDATING:**

 The 2nd Way bring the potential error: duplicate request (at the same time, like user double click) will create 2 invoices which is not what we want.

In the end, we use Distributed Lock and dont care about transaction using [DistributedLock](https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock) library

Comment: Just us an auto generated incremented number at the db level, don't worry about gaps. Gaps are awesome,

Comment: IN approach 2, if exception occurs. Wont it create gap?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja It wont, the number will return back to the Queue and next request (after the 2nd one) will pick it up.

Comment: But at a given time invoice will be with gaps. Anyway, I understood. 
IMO, second approach works great, low latency  than the first one. 
One thing I would like to add is even with second approach your invoice no at time t1  can be less than invoice no. at t2  (t2>t1).

Comment: Something has to block anyway, either this will be you or azure will do it for you.